# Django way to modify a database table using the contents of another table

Tags: python, mysql, django

Edited to clarify my meaning:

I am trying to find a method using a Django action to take data from one database table and then process it into a different form before inserting it into a second table. I am writing a kind of vocabulary dictionary which extracts data about students' vocabulary from their classroom texts. To do this I need to be able to take the individual words from the table field containing the content and then insert the words into separate rows in another table. I have already written the code to extract the individual words from the record in the first database table, I just need a method for putting it into a second database table as part of the same Django action.

I have been searching for an answer for this, but it seems Django actions are designed to handle the data for only one database table at a time. I am considering writing my own MySQL connection to inject the words into the second table in the database. I thought I would write here first though to see if anyone knows if I am missing a built-in way to do this in Django.

Comment: Apparently django isn't intelligent enough to figure out individual words from text. In fact, I don't think any framework would have something like that built-in. So why using django? Why not just write some python scripts to do it?

Comment: You've misunderstood my question, so maybe I did not write it clearly enough. I don't need Django to break the text into individual words. As you said, I can write my own Python script to do that. My question was, does Django have a way to put the words into a different DB table once I have processed the text into a list of separate words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hubert's answer is good and got me going in the right direction, but my usage scenario required a slightly different approach. Here are relevant lines from the code I wrote for inserting processed set of words into a database table after they have been processed:

```
# Update or create the words and counts in the Words table.
for word, count in words.iteritems():
    Word.objects.update_or_create(word=word, defaults={'count': count})
```

**words** in the function call *words.iteritems()* is a dictionary of containing words as keys and counts as values. **word** on the left side of the assignment in *update_or_create()* refers to the field in the database table

Using *update_or_create()* instead of *save()* means that if any editing is done to the source text of this operation at a later date, the word counts are updated in the database rather than completely new database rows being added.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there is no built-in way for something this specific. Finding single words in a text alone is a quite complex task if you take into consideration misspelled words, hyphen-connected words, quotes, all sorts of punctuation and unicode letters.

Your best bet would be using a regex for each text and save the matches on a second model manually.

Comment: I have already written the code to split the text into words. What I need now is the Django method for taking that data and inserting it into a second DB table. My problem at the moment seems to be that Django models are only designed to deal with one DB table at a time, not transfers of data between two separate tables. I may be missing something though.

I apologise for not being clearer about the specific information I was looking for.

Comment: Each django model represents one table. So it rather depends on how you want to save the dictionary. If it's only two columns with text then you need a model with two text fields.

Comment: It's two fields in two SEPARATE database tables. Models only seem to interact with one table at a time. I'm looking for interaction between two tables and therefore I am guessing two models. The reason why this is necessary is because the original text data comes from one record, but a text contains several different words, so inserting them will result in several records. Is this kind of interaction between two tables in Django possible or not? If it is not then I will go ahead and write my own MySQL connection for inserting the words in the database.

Comment: As I said each model represents one database table. If you need two tables with one column each then you need two models with one field each. For saving a row into two tables you'd do two save operations on the different model instances. You can have as many models as you want, of course. Just refer to the official docs which usually have multiple models in each example

Comment: I understood what you were saying, but what I need is a programmatic way of getting the data from one model to the other. I understand that two models represent two database tables. The problem is that getting the data extracted from one model to automatically move to the other model  appears to be either difficult or impossible.

Comment: Did you actually try it? It's pretty easy. Model1(field1=other.field2).save()

Comment: Thank you for this last comment. I am still fairly new to Django, so I had to search around in the Django docs to understand it, but it does appear to be the answer I was looking for.